# Amazon Postgres RDS: Update pg_attribute to update my custom attribute

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds, alter-table, catalogs

I want to update my attribute to change its length. I am getting

```
Error: Permission denied for relation pg_attribute.
```

My SQL Query is like this:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
UPDATE
    pg_attribute
SET
    atttypmod = 5+4
WHERE
    attname LIKE '%my_attribute%'
    AND atttypmod = 1 + 4;
END $$;
```

I have set `search_path` to my user, my user has the usage on schema `pg_catalog`. Is this possible? Because if not, we would have to drop the idea of RDS DB and move to ec2-instance and creating our own postgres db

UPDATE:

Granting permission with this command:

```
GRANT UPDATE ON pg_attribute TO rds_superuser;
```

Result is:

```
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "pg_attribute"
Query returned successfully with no result in 41 msec.
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve with it? Meddling with system tables is *risky business*, to say the least. Are you trying to change the maximum `length` of a `varchar` column, maybe?

Comment: Yeah, that particular column is present in a lot of tables across multiple schemas. So, we found it easier to update the column length of the attribute in this table so its reflected across and safe to migrate

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the length of many `varchar` columns (which isn't actually a *custom* attribute), you are better off using `ALTER TABLE` commands. You don't risk having unwanted side-effects, just in case PostgreSQL needs to do something more than changing the `pg_attributes` table. It might not do it today, but might do it in any future version.

You can have the database help you generate the `ALTER TABLE` DDL statements (or even, generate and execute them within a UDF).

To generate the DDL statements, you can use the `information_schema.columns` view; which is simpler to understand than using `pg_attributes` together with more catalog tables all joined. [The view actually joins several tables in non-obvious ways, but that's already done for you.]

You first check the columns involved:

```
-- Check the columns you are interested in
SELECT 
    table_schema, table_name, column_name, 
    data_type, character_maximum_length  
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    column_name like '%varchar_column%' 
    AND table_schema = 'my_schema' ;
```

You can get something like:

```
| table_schema | table_name |            column_name |         data_type | character_maximum_length |
|--------------|------------|------------------------|-------------------|--------------------------|
|    my_schema |         t1 |     one_varchar_column | character varying |                        5 |
|    my_schema |         t1 | another_varchar_column | character varying |                        6 |
|    my_schema |         t2 | a_third_varchar_column | character varying |                        3 |
```

Once you're sure the list of columns you get is the one you're actually interested, make the database compute the necessary DDL to perform what you want:

```
--
-- This will generate a collection of `ALTER TABLE` statements
--
-- This is what you're looking for
--
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE "' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '" ' ||
    '    ALTER COLUMN "' || column_name || '" TYPE VARCHAR(9);' AS ddl_to_execute
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    column_name like '%varchar_column%' 
    -- AND table_schema = 'my_schema'  
    -- AND whatever else you need
ORDER BY
    table_schema, table_name;
```

This will result in the following list of `ALTER TABLE` statements:

```
ALTER TABLE "my_schema"."t1" ALTER COLUMN "one_varchar_column" TYPE VARCHAR(9);
ALTER TABLE "my_schema"."t1" ALTER COLUMN "another_varchar_column" TYPE VARCHAR(9);
ALTER TABLE "my_schema"."t2" ALTER COLUMN "a_third_varchar_column" TYPE VARCHAR(9);
```

Copy them and execute them.

You can check the example at http://rextester.com/GYHR58531

Comment: I absolutely like this answer, unfortunately I can't accept it as a complete answer since mine is a custom attribute, from legacy application. But this won't be a complete answer. Also, since my reputation isn't high enough, not sure if you can see that I have marked your answer as helpful

Comment: What do you call a "custom attribute"? I guess is "someone doing some tricks and trying to save some time today at the expense of time spent tomorrow". If you are using the `atttypmod` column in a way PostgreSQL isn't expecting, the database *might* change its value to `NULL` or `0` or any default value for types that (from the databases perspective) don't need to store any information in that column. Again, it might work today, but your upgradeability is in danger...

Comment: @joanolo answer can be improved by adding a custom function, and doing it all in one transaction without any hand-editing.

CREATE FUNCTION execute(text) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 'begin execute _sql; return _sql; end';

SELECT execute('ALTER ...') (all the rest same as above)

Comment: @filiprem: Unless you are abosolutely sure that your `WHERE` clause isn't letting any unwanted column leak, I'd prefer to check before executing. I don't think this is something that needs to be done on a regular basis, but just a maintenance update when you decide that some columns weren't wide enough, or something along the lines.